# Windows 10: iTerm-like system-wide hotkey for showing PowerShell on any virtual desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

This is my iterm preferences window:

[image: This is my iterm preferences window]

Here I set a system-wide hotkey where if I press that hotkey, no matter what virtual desktop (or rather the OS X equivalent of virtual desktop) I'm on, my current terminal session will pop up.

It's incredibly convenient not having to switch away to a different virtual desktop in order to run a command. Is something like this possible?:

a hotkey that show/hides PowerShell no matter what virtual desktop I'm on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another application to open a Powershell window.  One option is [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), which I know can open Powershell and do the drop-down console thing.

Comment: Thanks for this. I went with cmder. They seem to be similar :)